# How do you call a string that matches /^\w+$/?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, string, naming

Strings that match /^\w+$/ are quite common. For example many authentication systems use that pattern to validate usernames. I'm wondering if a term exists that identifies this kind of strings.

I've been thinking of the term "alphanumeric" but is a string alphanumeric if it contains an underscore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that it is a good idea to give it a potentially confusing name. Alphanumeric could be misunderstood. If you need to refer to it, for example in your documentation, define it with an unique name like 'username_pattern', and refer to that definition of yours whenever you talk about it.

Answer (score 4):

From [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):
'\w       Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")'.

I personally call it a "word".

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion but wouldn't it be confusing to call "123" a word?

Comment: If '123' is a username, for example, it's a word, even though it is made of numerals.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I’d call it “a string that matches `^\w+$`” if my audience knows what this means. That is probably the most succint “name” that doesn’t significantly sacrifice accuracy. If I had to *say* it, I might call it “a non-empty string containing only word characters”, but once again I need to assume that my listener(s) know the technical meaning of *word character*.

If you want to come up with an English name for it, you are necessarily going to sacrifice a lot of accuracy and end up with something much more vague than the hard and well-defined regular expression — especially if your audience is not technical and/or does not recognise the term as a *technical* term with this precise meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with hlynur, (some) [POSIX character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) call this a word.
So it would be consistent to call this a word.

Comment: But then that would mean that you don't mind calling `123` a word.

Comment: Well, it _may_ be a word, then again it may be not. :-) What I tried to explain was: In another place there Is a name for this thing and it's a reasonable one -- why not use it?